# Arduino Mega 2560 -- Ports F & K as digital outs?

Tags: arduino, port

I'm stumped.. I'm simply attempting direct port manipulation of the pins on Ports F and K.

```
// First Set the port data direction registers as "outs"

DDRF = B11111111;  // GREEN LEDS - "ARMED"

DDRK = B11111111;  // YELLOW LEDS - DISARMED OFF HOOK"

DDRL = B11111111;  // RED - "ON HOOK"

//Then drive alternating pins High/Low

PORTF = B01010101; 

PORTK = B01010101;

PORTL = B01010101;
```

Port L works fine, the other two "no joy".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally enabled any of the overriding signals? See page 77 of the ATmega2560 datasheet

Answer (score 1):

Ports F & K are the ADC ports.  How do you have PORTF, DDRF, PINF, PORTK, DDRK, and PINK configured?

Comment: can you give an example of how they should be configured.

Answer (score 0):

PortF for example is On-Timer. This means that its used by some timer. In other words some of the pins supports PWM. You need to disable the apropriate timer for the duration of the read/write.
Check wiring_digital.c inside the arduino core main directory and youll get the idea.